# Как сделать middleware Vue+Laravel SPA?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, spa

Всем привет. К примеру у меня есть рут `admin/`, как к нему ограничить доступ? То есть пускать к нему только авторизованных пользователей и у тех которых есть поле `roleUser` со значение `'admin'`. Какие использовать хуки: глобальные или для конкретного рута?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто необходимо добавить все `middleware` к `route`, которые необходимы таким образом:
`Route::get('admin', 'SomeController@someMethod')->middleware(['auth', 'admin']);`
Первый `middleware` думаю понятен - он из коробки, второй придется сделать самому, примерно так:
1. php artisan make:middleware Admin
2. В нем пишем примерно следующее...

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::guest() || Auth::user()->roleUser != 'admin') {
            if($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()){
                return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => 'Forbidden'], 403);}
            abort(403);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

3. Регистрируем `middleware` здесь `app\Http\Kernel.php`

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        ....
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class
    ];
```

Более подробно все описано [тут](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware)